# Is this critical hit damage calculation correct?

Tags: dnd-5e, damage, critical-hit

I am  a Half Orc Fighter (Battle Master) 4/Paladin (Oath of Conquest) 5, wielding a Greataxe (d12)

Using a *[wish](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/wish)*, I have gained the *Brute* trait as it appears in the *Gladiator* from the Monster Manual:

> A melee weapon deals one extra die of its damage when [it hits] - (MM 346)

So on a regular hit, 2d12.

Half Orcs have the trait [*Savage Attacks*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/races/half-orc#Half-OrcTraits):

> When you score a critical hit with a melee weapon attack, you can roll one of the weapon's damage dice one additional time and add it to the extra damage of the critical hit. - (PHB 41)

This is **not** doubled, it is a bonus die, for a total of 5d12 on crit, yes? Yes.

If I take the Orc Racial Feat *Orcish Fury*:

> ...When you hit with an attack using a simple or martial weapon, you can roll one of the weapon's damage dice an additional time and add it as extra damage of the weapon's damage type. Once you use this ability, you can't use it again until you finish a short or long rest...- (XGtE 74)

This Does get doubled, Yes? 
7d12

As a Fighter (Battle Master) I could take *Maneuvering Attack*:

> When you hit a creature with a weapon attack, you can expend one superiority die to [add it] to the attack's damage roll...(PHB 74)

This Does get doubled, Yes?
7d12 + 2d8

The Paladin's *[Divine Smite](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/paladin#DivineSmite)* feature:

> ... when you hit a creature with a melee weapon attack, you can expend one paladin spell slot to deal radiant damage to the target, in addition to the weapon's damage. The extra damage is 2d8 for a 1st-level spell slot, plus 1d8 for each spell level higher than 1st, to a maximum of 5d8. - (PHB 85)

According to the above, this gets doubled as well? If I cast it at 2nd level,
7d12 + 2d8 + 6d8 radiant.

With *[Great Weapon Fighting Style](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/paladin#FightingStyle)*:

> When you roll a 1 or 2 on a damage die for an attack you make with a melee weapon that you are wielding with two hands, you can reroll the die and must use the new roll. The weapon must have the two-handed or versatile property for you to gain this benefit. - (PHB 84)

If the Critical Hit Rules allow doubling the dice of all these various sources of damage, because they are all part of the attack, I may then safely say I may reroll, at least once, any of these dice involved that result in a 1 or a 2, Yes?

My strength bonus is 5, and if I take the feat *Great Weapon Master* (PHB 167) I get -5 to the attack for +10 damage bonus.

7d12+2d8+15 plus 6d8 Radiant, rerolling the first results, at least on the d12s of 1 or 2.

Is this all correct?

Comment: @VittorioCarano ravery's answer is pretty great, yeah. The format of our site really relies on well expressed questions too, though, for the benefit of potential future askers. I've taken the liberty of suggesting an edit with what I believe you meant, and using direct quotes for extra clarity where you were referencing abilities in the rulebooks. If that's what you mean and you believe it's clear, you can accept the edit, and perhaps the question will be re-opened.

Comment: @VittorioCarano we have edited the necessary information into your question for you this time. Is everything correct? In the future, you cannot rely on answers to guess your intent, put that information into your question.

Comment: I understand. Thank you. Forgive yesterdays impatience, i realize today you were attempting to tutor me, for future posts and feedback.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Divine Smite says (emphasis mine):

> Starting at 2nd level, when you hit a creature with a melee weapon attack, you can expend one spell slot to deal radiant damage to the target, **in addition to the weapon's damage**.

This wording is a little ambiguous as to whether *Smite* is part of the attack damage or a damage modifier. Damage modifiers aren't doubled. However, [Sage Advice](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/615361420851478528) says that *Smite* is part of the attack damage and crittable since it does not require a save or its own attack roll.

The rest looks correct so you'd have:
Normal - 1d12 Slashing

- add *Brute* (MM p346) - 2d12 Slashing
- add *Orcish Fury* (Xanathar's p76) - 3d12 Slashing
- add *Maneuvering Attack* (PHB p74) - 3d12+1d8 Slashing
- add *Divine Smite* (PHB p85) - 3d12+1d8 Slashing + 3d8 Radiant
- add Crit, and *Savage Attack* (PHB p41) - 7d12+2d8 Slashing + 6d8 Radiant
- add strength bonus and *Great Weapon Master* (PHB p167) - 7d12+2d8+15 Slashing + 6d8 Radiant

*Great Weapon Fighting* (PHB p72) allows rerolls for an initial 1 or 2 on the d12 dice. The *Radiant Damage* and *Superiority Die* is in addition to weapon damage thus not covered by the GWF feature. ([Sage Advice](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/features/rules-answers-april-2016))

Notes:

- It's important to track the damage types due to possible damage resistance/immunity/reduction
- *Brute* (MM p.346) and *Orcish Fury* (Xanathar's p.76) are not core *Half-orc* feats; not all DM's will allow them.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, the critical damage rule says that any bonus dice added to the attack that was critical is doubled (Except those with a saving throw like poison).

> If the attack involves other
>   damage dice, such as from the rogue's Sneak Attack
>   feature, you roll those dice twice as well. (PH p.196)

The rerolling is applied to all dice in the attack.  So you are correct as far as I can see.

Comment: Hi James, welcome to the site. While your answer seems to be on right track, there are enough issues with the question that a slightly more detailed answer is probably in order. Also, your bit about the reroll doesn't agree with the answers to some related questions. If you could find some evidence to back it up, your answer would be far stronger.